# Salvar arquivo .doc no banco de dados com Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com `Djando` e `Python`.

Em `models.py`, para criar um objeto `cliente` com um nome, por exemplo, faço o seguinte:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

em `forms.py` faço o seguinte:

```
class ClienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('nome',)
        widgets = {'nome': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),}
        labels = {'nome': _('Nome'),}
```

mas como faço se esse campo ao invés de ser um campo de texto ser um arquivo `.doc`?

preciso anexar um documento word em cada cliente, algo como isso:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    documento = models.DOCUMENTO.DOC
```

Answer (score 1):

Django provê o tipo [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) para salvar binarios, voce pode definir da seguinte maneira:

```
doc_file = models.BinaryField(blank=True)
```

Mas atente bem para o que diz a documentação (Parte destacada [nesse link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield))

> Embora vc possa considerar armazenar arquivos em banco de dados, tenha em mente que esse design é ruim em 99% dos casos. Esse tipo de campo não é um substituto para o manuseio adequado de arquivos estáticos.